# What is the type of those methods of Class java.util.ArrayList<E>

Tags: java

The methods of Class java.util.ArrayList:

```
public E set(int index, E anEntry)
public boolean add(E anEntry)
public E remove(int index).
```

What are those methods' types? My guess is too ridiculous to post here...

Comment: Do some research into [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly the same thing it would mean if there was a class called `E`.

`set` is a method that takes an `int` (called `index`), an `E` (called `anEntry`) and returns another `E`.

`add` is a method that takes an `E` (called `anEntry`) and returns a `boolean`.

`remove` is a method that takes an `int` (called `index`) and returns an `E`.

Now, in this case `E` isn't a class - it's what is called a *type parameter*. If you look at the first line of `ArrayList` you will see something like this:

```
public class ArrayList<E>
```

which declares `E` as a type parameter of `ArrayList`. When you're talking about an `ArrayList<String>`, `E` means `String`. When you're talking about an `ArrayList<Integer>`, `E` means `Integer`. In this way they are sort of similar to normal method parameters - if you have `void x(int i)`, then when you call `x(5)`, `i` contains `5`. When you call `x(42)`, `i` contains `42`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); // E here is String

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // E in this case would be Integer
```

So E represents the type when you declare or instantiate the ArrayList. This is really helpful for compile time type check. Since you can not add any other type of object other than the one you created it with.

Example

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(); //if by mistake you try to add an 
                 //Integer object, it will give you a compile time error.
list1.add(new Integer(2)); // compile time error
```

Read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Answer (score 0):

1. E denotes the type of Object you stored in your ArrayList. For example it could be ArrayList of 'String', 'Integer' etc. 
   If you use `ArrayList<String>`, it returns String.
2. add() returns boolean type (true or false).

Answer (score 0):

`E` in this context is referring to Generics.
In Object Oriented Programming, generic types are used to create classes that can handle any data type. That's a simple explanation and while generics are a pretty in depth topic that should give you a good enough overview.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/